# How can you click an href link but block the linked page from displaying

Tags: html, rest, href

It was hard to encapsulate my question in the title.

I've rewritten a personal web page that made extensive use of javascript.  I'm simplifying matters (or so I hope).

I use a home automation server that has a REST interface.  I can send commands such as 'http://192.168.0.111/rest/nodes/7%2032%20CD%201/cmd/DON to turn on a light.  I'm putting links on my simplified web page using an href tag.  The problem is that it opens the rest interface page and displays the XML result.  I'd like to avoid having that page show up.  ie when you click on the link it 'goes' to the link but doesn't change the page.

This seems like it should/would not be possible but I've learned not to underestimate the community.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use ajax to send the request

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fetch` function if your browser is modern enough:

```js
document.querySelector(lightSelector).addEventListener('click', e => {
 e.preventDefault(); // prevent the REST page from opening
 fetch(lightURL).then // put promises here
})
```

The variables lightSelector and lightURL are expected to be defined somewhere.

The code listens for clicks on the link, and when one comes, we prevent the REST page from opening (your intention) then we send a request to your light URL with `fetch`. You can add some promises to deal with the response (e.g. print "light on" or "light off" for example) using `then` but that's another matter.

If you make the "link" a button, you can get rid of `e.preventDefault();` which is the part preventing the REST page from opening.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you possibly show me this in a simple HTML page format as my skills are very limited.  Given a URL for the controller of http://192.168.0.123 and a device address of '20 7F A4 1' the command would look something like http://192.168.0.123/rest/cmd/20 7F A4 1/DON to turn it on.  What would the web page look like if I wanted a simple <a href="http"//192.168.0.123/rest/modes/cmd/20 7F A4 1/DON">Turn Light On</a>link?

Comment: @Mark Hi again, you don't need to tweak the HTML in any way to make this work. You just add the JavaScript code.